# Why is this Recursive Iterator for file sizes in php not correct?

Tags: php, iterator, directory

I'm am trying to get file names, sizes and permissions in php using `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` .

The code below works for outputting all files and directory names and sizes correctly, but the permissions are wrong ( using get `$file->getPerms`).

In this case all permissions being output are the same, `0666` which I suspect is the first file only.

Also note that if I do not use `foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)` and instead just use `foreach($it as $file)` it works correctly, but it is not recursive ( aka it shows no sub-directories/files).

```
//remove some file types I don't want showing
$filetypes = array("jpg", "png", "css", "gif");


$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/root-directory");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {


      //foreach($it as $file) {
      // ^^This works but it's not recursive ?!

 //remove files in $filetypes array
 $filetype = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

 if (!in_array(strtolower($filetype), $filetypes)) {

//outputs file name correct
echo $file ;

//outputs wrong permissions      
echo substr(sprintf('%o', $file->getPerms()), -4);

//outputs file size correct
echo number_format($file->getSize()/1024, 2) . " KB"; 

 }
}
```

Comment: PHP Version 5.2.14 , oh also this is on a Wamp stack.

Comment: Octal fileperms on a WAMP stack? Please tell me how that should work :)

Comment: Just tested it on Lamp and works, I should have know ;) Still weird that non recursive seemed to work in windows.

Comment: Not going to work on Windows. As far as I know, file permissions on WAMP are always returned as `0666`.

Comment: Ya I just figured that out, can an admin close this question

Comment: For posterity, an answer should be written and accepted. Hakre or netcoder?

Comment: As for needing a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`; this is absolutely normal, to *iterate* over the contents of a *recursive iterator* the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` (or a child class thereof) must be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put this does not seem to return accurate results on a Wamp stack, possibly a bug.